# Is it possible for an app to sign data it generates so that the data can be guaranteed to come from the app?

Tags: digital-signature, key-management

Is it possible for an app binary to sign content generated by the app such that a verifier can confirm the data was indeed generated by a specific version of the app?

For example:
A mobile app from a trusted publisher generates a sequence of numbers based on a random seed or some other input. The app then packages the sequence of numbers and signs them in such a way that anyone with that package can be guaranteed that the package was generated by a specific version of the app.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your previous question?